# unable to view pages after adding Authnticate middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am learning Laravel for a few days now. While checking the kernel.php file i added the **Authenticate** middleware in the global middleware array, which by default has only the **CheckForMaintenanceMode** middleware.

```
protected $middleware = [
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class
];
```

But since adding the **Authenticate** middleware i am unable to reach(i don't mean access, i mean reach the page itself) any page on my browser. On chrome it says something like this:

```
"This page isn’t working

blog.dev redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
```

Can anyone please tell why? If i remove the Authenticate middleware the pages are reachable again. Note that i have no middleware registered in my web.php file for the routes. Just trying to understand how things work with authentication in Larave.

Comment: Don't understand why the negative vote!! It's not very obvious - the infinite loop that it creates when the Auth middleware is added to global middleware stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added `Authenticate` middleware as a global middleware.

Excerpt from the documentation -

If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class in the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

If you are not logged in you can not access any page & to login you have to access atleast login form. But you can't cause you're not logged in. This creates infinte loop.

Thats why you're unable to access any page.

Reference - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware

Comment: Yes i already read the documentation but was not able to figure out the infinite loop it creates. How did i miss it?! Thanks much!